# Sitecore connector for content hub's specific item not available after installation

Tags: content-hub

We tried to install the `Sitecore connector for Content Hub 5.1` in the azure sitecore cm app service. The `deploy.ps1` script ran successfully for installation and I could see the files available in the **App_config**, **bin**, and other folders, but when I tried to insert the media in the **Image** field from the content hub then the option for inserting the media was not available like shown in the screenshot below it should have been there but it is not available.

[image]

So I tried to check if the required items are installed in the `master` and `core` db but no items are installed.

Do you have any idea how to troubleshoot this or if someone encountered this?

FYI: We are using `Sitecore 10.3`

Comment: Did you follow all the installation instructions here? https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/connect-for-ch/51/connect-for-content-hub/walkthrough--deploying-sitecore-connect-for-content-hub-in-an-existing-paas-environment.html

Comment: Yes @RichardSeal I followed the same steps only 5th step I did not do from section "Prepare an installation folder" because we are using SC 10.3.